# Magento: Edit existing line items in an order

Tags: php, magento

Can we edit existing lineitems in an order (Change Status, quantities ordered, quantities processed, Price, Discount amount) ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to edit it manually in the Back Office.

1. You can change them through action in BO
2. You can write your code loading models from Mage_Sales_Model_* (Mage_Sales_Model_Order, Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item etc.) and operate on them
3. You can change manually data in PHPMyAdmin in the tables

   - sales_flat_order
   - sales_flat_order_item